# Jquery form validation coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

My Jquery validation is not working, below is the script coding.  I am getting a

> `Fatal error: Uncaught exception`

error and not sure why.  I know one of the reasons can be the validation code isnt correct. Is the coding correct or is there errors?

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$('form#contact').submit(function(e) {

    var isValidZip = /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(jQuery('#form_zip').val());
    var isValidYear = /^\d{4}$/.test(jQuery('#gradDate').val());
    var year_number = parseInt(jQuery('#gradDate').val());
    var isValidEmail = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(jQuery('#form_email').val());
    var first_name = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#first_name').val());
    var last_name = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#last_name').val());
    var form_email = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#form_email').val());
    var street = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#street').val());
    var city = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#city').val());
    var state = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#state').val());
    var isValidPhone = /^[2-9]\d{2}[2-9]\d{2}\d{4}$/.test(jQuery('#phone_day').val());

    function validZip(zip)
    {
        if (zip.match(/^[0-9]{5}$/)) {
            return true;
        }
        zip=zip.toUpperCase();
        if (zip.match(/^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (zip.match(/^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z].[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

        if(!validZip(jQuery('#form_zip').val())){
            alert('Please enter a valid Zip Code.');
        }

        else if(!isValidYear || (year_number > <?php echo date('Y')?>)){
            alert('Please enter a valid High School Graduation Year.');
        }

        else if(!isValidEmail (jQuery('#form_email').val())){
            alert('Please enter a valid Email Address.');
        }   

        else if(first_name.length <= 0 || first_name == 'First Name' || (!first_name.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) || (first_name.match(/[0-9]/))){
            alert('Please enter your First Name.');
        }
        else if(last_name.length <= 0 || last_name == 'Last Name' || (!last_name.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) || (last_name.match(/[0-9]/))){
            alert('Please enter your Last Name.');
        }
        else if(street.length <= 0 || street == 'Street Address'){
            alert('Please enter your Street Address.');
        }
        else if(city.length <= 0 || city == 'City'){
            alert('Please enter your City.');
        }
        else if(state.length <= 0 || state == 'State'){
            alert('Please enter your State by 2 letter abbreviation.');
        }
        else if(country.length <= 0 || country == 'Other'){
            alert('Please enter your Country.');
        }
        else if(!isValidPhone){
            alert('If your phone number is correct, close this box and then Click the button in the form.');
        }
        else {
            $('form#mainform').submit();    
        }
            return false;       
        }
        return false;
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: No I have not solved yet

Answer (score 0):

You have php inside your JavaScript code:

```
else if(!isValidYear || (year_number > <?php echo date('Y')?>)){
```